# Is it possible to use React with material ui in php?

Tags: php, reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to coding and I want to use `reactjs` in `php`.
When using React on another website you can add script tags and load React in to it.

```
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
```

I added my react component and linked it in a script tag.
Only when I use import statements like from `material-ui` inside my react component, it stops working.

I also used the babel online converter to convert my `reactjs` component into jsx. But then I get the following:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined.

I guess it does not work because of the linked scripts (above) which most likely don't have any `material-ui` libraries included.

I do not want to create a React app and use `php` in it. Is it possible to use `php` and `reactjs` with material-ui inside php? Or am I on a complete wrong track here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[material-ui](https://material-ui.com/) for react is a third party library and is not available via react CDN/script that you are adding.

You'll need to include another script for `material-ui`

Development: https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js

Production: https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.production.min.js

You can read more about setting up material ui via CDN [here](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/#cdn) and [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/cdn).